npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@10.11.0 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm
Tatke a look into following cypress node.js error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)enter code here
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object. (/Users/sanjeevchaudhary/Desktop/WorkspaceCypress/snypr-test-integration/node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js:43:29)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@10.11.0 postinstall: node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@10.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output

If someone is facing the error above then:
install the latest Node.js :
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current and try, It will resolve the issue. In my case it resolved the issue. Thank you!!
